# Ionic 2: Login with Linked In

Tags: ionic2, linkedin-api

I'm trying to implement login/register with linked in my ionic 2 application. Referring this [linked official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2.) for the same purpose. According to the documentation first Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 must be performed. To do so, I found few solutions on web to use in app browser. Below is my current code that executes on click of login with linked in button.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

export class LoginPage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ) {}

 const browser =
 this.iab.create('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=81zzocd5beagbo&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=STATE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8100&scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_share');


     browser.show();

}
```

I'm facing below problem now.

1. After linked in successful login it will be redirected to the redirect URL that that is specified in the developer.linkedin.com website, which will be mentioned  during the creation of app.
2. I need to know what is the URL that I have to specify so that after successful login/cancel it will be redirected back to the app.
3. And How can I extract the **code, state** from that particular URL which is used further for calling the linkedin get API's to get user details.
4. Or if there are any best practises for login/register with linkedIn please update me.

**Note:** I have already referred ionic 2 [linked in plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/linkedin/). But unless the user has installed linkedin app in  his device, we cannot use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

2. I need to know what is the URL that I have to specify so that after successful login/cancel it will be redirected back to the app.

> http://localhost/callback

Above will solve url call back url issue.

I know you cant use IONIC LINKEDIN PLUGIN because it works when LinkedIn app in installed on device.

Below is the code which I used to login to LinkedIn and get details of logged in user.

```
public linkedInLogin(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      var browserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&state=XXXXXXXX&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress")
      browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
        console.log("event.url 1 -> " + event.url);
        if ((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {
          browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => { });
          browserRef.close();
          console.log("event.url 2 -> " + event.url);
          var parsedResponse = {};

          var code = (event.url.split("=")[1]).split("&")[0];
          var state = event.url.split("=")[2];

          if (code !== undefined && state !== null) {
            console.log("code : " + code + "  state : " + state);
            parsedResponse["code"] = code;
            //parsedResponse["state"] = state;
            resolve(parsedResponse);
          } else {
            reject("Problem authenticating with LinkedIn");
          }
        }
      });
      browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function (event) {
        reject("The LinkedIn sign in flow was canceled");
      });
    });
  }
```

In the above function replace code and state and put your code and state which you get from LinkedIn Developers account.

```
public linkLogin() {
    let loader;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.linkedInLogin().then(success => {
        console.log(" Success : " + success.code);
        let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers
        });
        var data: any;
        data = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + success.code + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXX";

        console.log("data : " + data);
        let body = data;
        console.log("body : " + body);
        this.http.post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", body, options).toPromise()
          .then(res => {
            let result = res.json();
            console.log("http result : " + result);

            if (result["access_token"] !== undefined) {
              console.log("Done : " + result["access_token"]);
              loader = this.load.create({
                content: "Please wait"
              }).present();

              this.getLinkedInUserDetails(result["access_token"]).then(response => {
                console.log("http response : " + JSON.stringify(response));  

              }).then(() => {

                    console.log("LinkedIn authentication completed.");                  
                    loader.dismiss();

                });
              });
            } else {
              //return resolve("Failed");
              console.log("Failed");
            }
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            //return resolve("Failed");
            console.log("Failed");
          });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log("error : " + error);
      });
    });
  }
```

In the above function replace client_Id and client_Secret with yours.

```
getLinkedInUserDetails(token: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token//,

    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers,

    });

    return this.http.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json", options).toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json(), err => err);
  }
```

This is long code but I found this is the best approach to worked with LinkedIn in ionic 2.

Hope this answer helps.

Let me know if you have any query/error in the above code.

Comment: Hi Irfan thanks for the reply. If I use http://localhost/callback as a redirect URL I'm getting error "Application refused, connection refused". Can you let me know what is the call back url that I can use.

Comment: Hi Vasanth, u are most welcome. Did u added  " Authorized Redirect URLs" on your linkedIn developer account? Check out the image on this Link : http://imgur.com/a/BSw7w

Comment: Ya Irfan, I have already done that. After successful login I'm getting this error http://imgur.com/a/sloLQ

Comment: And Irfan, Have you implemented above code in ionic 2 or 1

Comment: Its done in Ionic 2 ..I am checking the error which you got..il figure out the solution for u in sometime hopefully..

Comment: Are you testing this feature by running Ionic serve command?? ..don't use this command also "ionic run android -l"..you can test this only  on device by running "Ionic run android" command..let me know if this works

Comment: I'm using ionic's in app browser plugin. http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/ it has o option for open. If I  directly use  cordova.InAppBrowser.open(  It will throw error cordova undefined.

Comment: Use " cordova.InAppBrowser.open" method...Inorder to fix cordova undefined error do this --> Paste this after ur import statements "declare var cordova: any;"

Comment: Hi Irfan, now the cordova error is solved. But the redirect URL issue still remains pending. I'm testing in device it self. After successful login I'm getting same error http://imgur.com/a/sloLQ.

Comment: can you tel me which version of cordova inAppBrowser plugin u have installed

Comment: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.0

Comment: can you update it to 1.7.1 and try..because i am using 1.7.1 and it works well for me

Comment: I'm sorry to inform Irfan, tried everything stil not working... same error is coming ..

Comment: OMG ..sorry @Vasanth i dont know why u are getting that error..will research on that more if i get any solution il post here